# Getting random positions correctly from a C array

Tags: c, random

first of all, I'm a newbie in C so that I've been struggling to learn some simple things. That's the issue I want to pick random questions from the array questions, I need to create the following logic process, the program is going to start asking any question from the array, and after the user reply the question I want to save the reply in one array and the question in another, I want to save the questions already asked because I don't want the program to repeat the question so that I'll save it and check if the questions have already been done, and the answers I will save because I'll compare to another array with the right questions into it. Here's my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


int main()
{
  char questions[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c','d'};
  char reply[4];
  char aux[4];

  int i =0;
  time_t t;
  srand((unsigned)time(&t));

  do{

      printf("%c\n", questions[rand()%4]);
      scanf("%*c\n");


      aux[i] = questions[rand()%4];

    }while( i < 4);

  return 0;
}
```

The problem is that the script stops in the first question, I can't manage to get the other ones, so please what am I doing wrong here?

---

I edited the original code, I really don't know if it's allowed, anyway, I made some changes in the code, based on usefull answers I got from here, but the code keeps with a odd behave, If you compile it you can see that you're just able to introduce the first answer because after you press enter It will be listed all the values from the array questions, someone can explain to me why this happens, I tryed to debbug the code but a had no clue about the error.

Comment: This doesn't compile: `foo.c:19:20: error: ‘array’ undeclared (first use in this function)` Can you post a version which does compile?

Comment: You never initialize `i`, so it will have an *indeterminate* (and seemingly random or garbage) value. And the loop you have doesn't modify `i` which means the loop condition is all wrong.

Comment: Also, `scanf("%s\n",reply[i])` is *very* wrong as `%s` reads a null-terminated string but `reply[i]` is a single `char`. And `i` is invalid anyway (see my previous comment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, and you want a way to generate the set of questions in a random order each time, ensuring you don't ask the same question twice, while also ensuring that all questions are asked -- then you want to track what questions are asked with a *frequency array*. A frequency array is an array with one element for each thing in your collection of objects -- *initialized zero* to begin. (in your case you want a 4-element array - each element corresponds to a question)

Take for example:

```
  char questions[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c','d'};
  int asked[4] = {0};   /* frequency array to track questions already asked */
```

When you begin, all elements of `asked` are initialized zero. This indicates that none of the questions have been asked.

When you generate a random number for your question (e.g. `int q = rand() % 4;`), you check if that element in the `asked` array is zero, if so, you ask that question and you increment:

```
    asked[q]++;                 /* increment element of freq array noting asked */
```

If the question has already been asked, then `asked[q]` will be non-zero, and you simply generate another random number in the range until you find a question that has not been asked, e.g.

```
    while (asked[q])            /* loop if already marked in asked array */
      q = rand() % 4;           /* get new random 0 - 3 */
```

Then you are sure you have a question that has not been asked and you simply:

```
    printf ("%c.) ....\n", questions[q]);
```

Putting it altogether, you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main (void)
{
  char questions[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c','d'};
  int asked[4] = {0};   /* frequency array to track questions already asked */
  
  srand(time(NULL));

  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    int q = rand() % 4;         /* get random 0 - 3 */
    
    while (asked[q])            /* loop if already marked in asked array */
      q = rand() % 4;           /* get new random 0 - 3 */
    asked[q]++;                 /* increment element of freq array noting asked */
    
    printf ("%c.) ....\n", questions[q]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/randquestions
a.) ....
d.) ....
c.) ....
b.) ....
```

or

```
$ ./bin/randquestions
d.) ....
c.) ....
a.) ....
b.) ....
```

Look things over and let me know if I understood correctly, or if you have any further questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%c\n",reply[i]);
```

invokes *undefined behavior* because `char*` is expected for `%c`, but `char` is passed.

In this case `reply` is not used otherwise, so the input can be ignored.
This can be done by adding `*` to the input specifyer like

```
scanf("%*c\n");
```

If you want the input to be stored, add `&` before `reply[i]` to get a pointer of the place to store the input.

```
scanf("%c\n",&reply[i]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how why to ignore input since I need to save the answer for each question in another array, I mean is there any way to save it into the while loop?

Comment: Thanks again, I did most of the things you said so far is working but there is something quite wrong because after I input the answer for the first question, the other questions are listed in a row